# Test a website in multiple browsers

Tags: web-testing, multiple-browsers

I would like to test a webpage in multiple browsers, in my local machine. I see that most of the online services provide screenshots, but I cant really see what happens when i click a link on the webpage.

Are there any software where i can see how the webpage is actually functioning on user events like click etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only tool I known is [Selenium](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://seleniumhq.org/&ei=uWPOTo3EEoXHgAen_oE_&usg=AFQjCNHCelhj_BWssRX2H0HZCcPqhgBrRg)

hope it helps!

Comment: Does Selenium provide realtime access? I mean, Will i be able to manually browse the site in the browser I choose?

Comment: Selemium if for automatic testing with the browser. You create a script the will click using Firefox/IE/Chrome/etc and check if some error was raised. If you want to do it the manual way I dont see the problem, use virtual machines?